# 3DWeb Viewer issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, viewer, cityengine

I have been putting together a textured multipatches, DEM, polygon data (road, pavement), point data (trees with 3d symbology) and have been trying to share my model using the export to 3d web scene arcToolbox tool.

[image: ArcScene view]

But only raster data (DEM and shadow map) are displayed in CItyEngine Web Viewer. I upload .3ws file in ArcGiS Online, earlier created AOI in the Scene.

Any suggestions?

[image: CityEngine Web Viewer]